# Changing texture of game but the image is not replaced according to cocos hd defination

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I am making a game in cocos2d. I am checking the level of the sprite and updating the texture accordingly.
Now at start the image is placed in hd alright.. now when the game starts and i start moving the sprite the hd image is replaced with the normal one. I am checking the replacing the texture with this code.

```
int value = [self.weapon.weaponLevel intValue];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *imageView = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
CCTexture2D *frame = [[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:imageView];
[self.player setTexture:frame];
```

Can any one please help me out here. Thanks.
regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to go through `NSBundle` and `UIImage` when you can use `CCTextureCache` that handles all the path resolution and HD/SD detection internally.

Plus, as the name implies, it caches the texture so that the subsequent use of the same sprite file would be faster:

Here is what you need:

```
CCTexture2D *frame = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"name.png"];
[self.player setTexture:frame];
```